# Dudley's integral inequality: tail bound

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics, inequality

This is problem 8.1.7 in Vershynin's High Dimensional Probability book.

Let $(X_t)_{t\in T}$ be a random process indexed by a metric space $(T,d)$ with sub-gaussian increments(i.e. $||X_t-X_s||_{\psi_2} \leq Kd(s,t)$ for all $s,t\in T$). Then for every $u\geq 0$, the event

$$ \sup_{t,s\in T} |X_t-X_s| \leq CK \left( \int_0^\infty \sqrt{\log\mathcal{N}(T,d,\epsilon)} d\epsilon + u \text{diam}(T) \right)$$

with probability $1-2\exp(u^2)$ where $C$ is just some absolute constant.

If we assume $T$ is second countable then we may prove it just for the case when $T$ is finite by applying dominated convergence theorem and apply a limit argument. Furthermore, the tail bound is trivially true when $T$ is unbounded so assume $\text{diam}(T)<\infty$. With these assumptions, lets move on to the issues I'm having proving the result.

To prove this result we are given the following hints. Define $\epsilon_k=2^{-k}$ and $T_k$ is an $\epsilon_k$ covering of with cardinality $|T_k|=\mathcal{N}(T,d,\epsilon_k)$. Then if $t\in T$ we define $\pi_k(t)\in T_k$ to be the closest element in $T_k$ to $t_0$ for some fixed element $t_0$. In particular we can show that

$$\sup_{t\in T} (X_{\pi_k(t)}-X_{\pi_{k-1}(t)}) \leq CK\epsilon_{k-1}(\sqrt{\log|T_k|}+z)$$

with probability at least $1-2\exp(-z^2)$. So proving this was fairly straight forward.
The next hint was to prove a bound for

$$ \sup_{t\in T} |X_t-X_{t_0}| \leq CK \left( \int_0^\infty \sqrt{\log\mathcal{N}(T,d,\epsilon)} d\epsilon + u \text{diam}(T) \right)$$

using the previous result. We note that we can write

$$\int_0^\infty \sqrt{\log\mathcal{N}(T,d,\epsilon)} d\epsilon + u \text{diam}(T) = \int_0^{\text{diam}(T)}\left( \sqrt{\log\mathcal{N}(T,d,\epsilon)} + u \right) d\epsilon$$

Since $T$ is finite there exists a $\kappa_0, K_0 \in \mathbb{Z}$ such that $T_{\kappa_0} = \{t_0\}$ and $T_{K_0} = T$. So we can write

$$\int_0^{\text{diam}(T)}\left( \sqrt{\log\mathcal{N}(T,d,\epsilon)} + u \right) d\epsilon \sim \sum_{k\geq{\kappa_0+1}} \epsilon_{k-1}\left( \sqrt{\log\mathcal{N}(T,d,\epsilon_k)} + u \right) $$

Next we form the chain and note that $\pi_{k_0}(t) = t_0$ and $\pi_{K_0}(t)=t$ so we have

$$\sup_{t\in T}|X_t-X_{t_0}|\leq \sum_{k=\kappa_0+1}^{K_0} \sup_{t\in T}|X_{\pi_k(t)}-X_{\pi_{k-1}(t)}|$$

If we let

$$\sup_{t\in T}|X_t-X_{t_0}|\geq CK\sum_{k=\kappa_0+1}^{K_0}\epsilon_{k-1}\left( \sqrt{\log\mathcal{N}(T,d,\epsilon_k)} + z_k \right)$$

be our event $E$ then from a union bound we have

$$P(E) \leq 2\sum_{k=\kappa_0+1}^{K_0}\exp(-z_k^2)$$

Vershynin then suggests we choose $z_k=u+\sqrt{k-\kappa_0}$. If we plug this into our sum we get $$2\sum_{k=\kappa_0+1}^{K_0}\exp(-z_k^2) \leq \exp(-u^2)$$

So, in particular, we have that by another union bound that

$$ \sup_{s,t\in T}|X_s-X_{t}|\geq 2CK\sum_{k=\kappa_0+1}^{K_0}\epsilon_{k-1}\left( \sqrt{\log\mathcal{N}(T,d,\epsilon_k)} + u + \sqrt{k-\kappa_0} \right)$$

Has probability less than $2\exp(-u^2)$

Which is almost a larger event than the original one were proving. My only issue is how to absorb the additional term $\sum_{k=\kappa_0+1}^{K_0} \epsilon_{k-1} \sqrt{k-\kappa_0}$. If I can deal with that I have what I wanted to prove because

$$  2CK\int_0^\infty \sqrt{\log\mathcal{N}(T,d,\epsilon)} d\epsilon + u \text{diam}(T) \geq C' 2CK\sum_{k=\kappa_0+1}^{K_0}\epsilon_{k-1}\left( \sqrt{\log\mathcal{N}(T,d,\epsilon_k)} + u \right)$$

Answer (score 1):

I'm solving the exact same exercise on Vershynin. The problem is actually much simpler.

Some hint:

$\epsilon_k=\epsilon_\kappa/2^{k-\kappa}\le diam(T)/2^{k-\kappa}.$

You will likely need the following elementary calculation

$$\sum_{k=1}^\infty (\frac{1}{2})^k \sqrt{k}\le \sum_{k=1}^\infty (\frac{1}{2})^k k=2.$$

Answer (score 0):

I think this term was actually smaller than some $M$, because as k goes from $\kappa_0+1$ to $K_0$, the term $\epsilon_{k-1}$ drops exponential fast and $\sqrt{k-\kappa_0}$ grows much slower than that. Try to apply Able's to see the series actually converge, hence this partial sum is bounded by some constant M. And then by choose a $C$ large enough you can simply drop this constant $M$. I was just in this chapter today, and THIS MIGHT BE WRONG because I was trying to see the answer which has lead me here. Just let me know if you agree or not.